# Yii2 ActiveForm decimal format value from JSON data

Tags: model, yii2, decimalformat, active-form

I want to display decimal format by parseJSON(data).

ActiveFrom A get data from Model B by parseJSON(data). (both data fromat type is decimal(15,2)

Here ActiveFrom A

```
                <?= $form->field($model, 'budget_id')->widget(Select2::className(),
                [
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Budget::find()->all(), 'id', 'description'),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select ...', 'id'=>'code',],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,],
                    'disabled' => !$model->isNewRecord,
                ]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'budget')->textInput(['readonly' => true,'disabled' => !$model->isNewRecord,]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'actual')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'type' => 'decimal','disabled' => !$model->isNewRecord,]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'available')->textInput(['readonly' => true,'disabled' => !$model->isNewRecord,]) ?>
```

select data from `budget_id` dropdownlist and will get `budget`, `actual`and `available` data by parseJSON(data)

JQuery parseJSON(data)

```
$script = <<< JS
$('#code').change(function(){
    var ioId = $(this).val();
    $.get('../budget/get-data',{ ioId : ioId }, function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#budget_budget').val(data.budget);
        $('#budget_actual').val(data.actual);
        $('#budget_available').val(data.available);
    });
});
```

model rule()

```
[['amount',  'actual', 'available','budget'], 'number'],
```

[image: view]

how to display decimal format by getting data from parseJSON(data).

Comment: the image shown has the values assigned as decimal what is your actual question? and you can use `$.getJSON` to Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a `GET HTTP` request rather than parsing manually with `$.get`

Comment: oh,  I'm sorry just need to display velue with 
'thousandSeparator' => ','
something like this  
8835220.00    =   8,835,220.00

Comment: so you want a currency formater which should format the amount after updating the input field, like below `10,000.00` ?

Comment: yes, sir. it about formatter.
but field : 'actual', 'available','budget' get value automatic from drop downlist 'budget_id' 
then why I make field : 'readonly' => true
I don't want to change or update input field 'actual', 'available','budget' 
just want to display currency formatter.

Comment: thats ok , you can have a readonly input too i added an answer below for you , see if that helps you out

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`yii2-money`**](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-money) to create a formatted input that will automatically handle the currency formatting for all your inputs and example usage is given below.

Either run

```
$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-money "dev-master"
```

or add

```
"kartik-v/yii2-money": "dev-master"
```

to the `require` section of your `composer.json` file..

```
<?=
 $form->field ( $model , 'budget' )->widget ( MaskMoney::classname () , [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'prefix' => '$ ' ,
        'suffix' => ' ¢' ,
        'allowNegative' => false
    ]
] );
?>
```

See [**`HERE`**](http://demos.krajee.com/money#usage) for detailed usage.